# How can I get rid of the "setting a property that has only a getter" warning?

Tags: firefox, firebug

For quite a while now I keep getting an annoying "setting a property that has only a getter" message in Firebug's *Console* panel on each page I browse (not only mine).

Any idea what could cause it? And how I can fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/110155/firebug-always-showing-javascript-error-setting-a-property-that-has-only-a-gette

Comment: Look at this: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=9131

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. It appears nobody found a solution yet, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Even when this question is quite old already I want to give an answer.

DOM properties can have [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters). Changing a property, which has only a setter function defined.

While I remember this warning appeared in former versions of Firefox, it seems in current versions (tested with Firefox 13.0.1 + Firebug 1.9.2) it just silently fails.

Also note that this message comes from Firefox, Firebug just displays the warnings inside it's [*Console* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel). Also note that you can control the logging of warnings and errors via the panel's options menu.

Comment: Thanks, I still don't know what triggered it, but it seems it doesn't appear anymore.